# Warning when setting a delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to pass data back with the segue, and am following this answer: [How to Pass information Back in iOS when reversing a Segue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586123/how-to-pass-information-back-in-ios-when-reversing-a-segue)

However when I try to put this line in:

```
@property (nonatomic) id<MyDataDelegate> delegate;
```

I get the following warning:

[image]

And when I try to put  to the first view controller like this:

```
@interface ContainerViewController : UIViewController <MyDataDelegate>
```

I get the error "`Cannot find protocol declaration for 'MyDataDelegate'` " and I did include the other header file...

Comment: @property(weak,nonatomic) id <MyDataDelegate>delegate;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message it looks like you are adding the property to a subclass of `UIPageViewController`. But `UIPageViewController` already has a `delegate` property of a different type.

You therefore need to either rename your property to something else, or declare `MyDataDelegate` to conform to `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` so that your property redeclaration is compatible with the base class version:

```
@protocol MyDataDelegate <UIPageViewControllerDelegate>

...

@end
```

You also need to declare your property with the `weak` attribute.

Comment: This indeed fixes the warning, but when I add @interface ContainerViewController : UIViewController <MyDataDelegate> I still get the error like I said in my question

Comment: @nonuma If your delegate header file is also including the controller header, you have a cyclical dependency. Make sure your protocol doesn't include the controller's header (forward declaration `@class ...` may be necessary).

Comment: @Mike Weller I did everything now from the link I said before, and now I'm stuck here:         PageScrollViewController.delegate = self; the compiler tells me he couldn't found the property on the object of type PageScrollViewController...but I did add it as property?