# Stuck when passing data back with segue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to pass data back with the segue using protocols. I'm following this answer: [How to Pass information Back in iOS when reversing a Segue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586123/how-to-pass-information-back-in-ios-when-reversing-a-segue)

So what I already did:

**PageScrollViewController.h**

```
@protocol MyDataDelegate <NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDelegate>

- (void)recieveData:(NSString *)theData;

@end
```

and I also added the property:

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<MyDataDelegate> delegate;
```

**ContainerViewController.h**

```
#import "PageScrollViewController.h"

@interface ContainerViewController : UIViewController <MyDataDelegate>

//...
```

**ContainerViewController.m**

```
- (void)recieveData:(NSString *)theData {

    //Do something with data here
}
```

and here I'm stuck:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    //Get a handle on the view controller about be presented
    PageScrollViewController *secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    if ([PageScrollViewController isKindOfClass:[PageScrollViewController class]]) {
        PageScrollViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

The line  `PageScrollViewController.delegate = self;` gives an error: Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'PageScrollViewController' but I did add it as a property and synthesized it...

Comment: Have you `#imported` PageScrollViewController?

Comment: Yes, in the header file of ContainerViewController

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to call an *instance method* (`[PageScrollViewController setDelegate:]`) on  an object of type [`Class`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/class) (in this case, `PageScrollViewController`).

**Try this:**

Replace

```
PageScrollViewController *secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

  if ([PageScrollViewController isKindOfClass:[PageScrollViewController class]]) {
    PageScrollViewController.delegate = self;
  }
```

With

```
PageScrollViewController *secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

  if ([secondViewController isKindOfClass:[PageScrollViewController class]]) {
    secondViewController.delegate = self;
  }
```